# Heat exchanger design guidance

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, heat-exchanger

I need to design a water to air heat exchanger with a blower for a small greenhouse as an engineering project. There aren't much design specifications - only that it must maintain a temperature of between 15 and 25 degrees celsius during winter nights (-4 degrees celsius approx) the material of the box it will be placed in is polycarbonate with dimensions 1x1x1,5m.

I am looking for a good source or a textbook to work from for the design of the heat exchanger as well as  determining all the variables. it is a semester project and have just started with the design, if somebody could guide me in a direction I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't do much heat tranfer stuff now, but I used my textbook from a graduate heat exchanger design course I took, [Process Heat Transfer by Hewitt, Shires and Bott](http://www.dl.begellhouse.com/buynow/book/7daba87f6fb65d65.html). It has all of the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found one called Engineering Heat Transfer by Simonson J. R, but it was well written and had examples. Used it to size a heat exchanger for buildings which came out well. But any of the heat transfer books or heat exchanger books will give you the basic design parameters.

Here is a link to one : http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Engineering-Heat-Transfer-by-Simonson-J-R-Author-9780333459997-/172390036831?hash=item28233f355f:g:0EwAAOSwB09YExgD , not cheap though - any second-hand bookshops near you?

Comment: Thank you, I found an ebook version but the heat exchanger chapter does not have all the information I need.